# Cannot find module 'gulp-concat'

Tags: gulp

```
$ gulp
module.js:549
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'gulp-concat'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\xampp\htdocs\irismuzhotel-merchant\gulpfile.js:2:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
```

I have already installed Gulp and tried to run a project but this error stops me half way. I have seen this link (https://github.com/EventStore/EventStore.UI/issues/16) but don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, I got it... Tho it's not the same module, it's the same way to fix it...

I've referred this link (https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-concat) and some errors regarding other modules emerged but can be fixed by installing those modules the same way. All depends on what modules required our gulpfile.js